# Efficiently aggregating on a script field (object with many attributes) in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a two level data structure that I'm trying to search and produce statistics on. Let's imagine the data is posts and comments. It would look something like this:

```
[
  {"title": "Post 1", "comments": [
    {"name": "Comment 1", "date": "2019-01-10", "character_count": 1000},
    {"name": "Comment 2", "date": "2019-01-11", "character_count": 2000},
    {"name": "Comment 3", "date": "2019-01-12", "character_count": 1500},
    {"name": "Comment 4", "date": "2019-01-13", "character_count": 2500},
    {"name": "Comment 5", "date": "2019-01-15", "character_count": 3000}
  ]},
  {"title": "Post 2", "comments": [
    {"name": "Comment 1", "date": "2019-01-10", "character_count": 400},
    {"name": "Comment 2", "date": "2019-01-13", "character_count": 500},
    {"name": "Comment 3", "date": "2019-01-15", "character_count": 4000},
  ]}
]
```

Several notes on the data:

- Every "comment" has way more attributes than just `character_count` (probably 30).
- There aren't very many "comments" per "post", rarely over 200, and usually under 30.
- There are thousands of "posts".
- In the mapping, "comments" are a nested object.

When making the query, I'm only interested in one "comment" per "post", based on date. For a certain date, I need the latest comment that comes before that date. I'm able to get this data using a scripted field:

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "relevant_comment": {
      "script": "sorted = _source.comments.findAll { it.date < report_date } . sort { a, b -> b.date <=> a.date }; return sorted ? sorted.first() : null;",
      "params": {
        "report_date": "2019-01-12"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So for "2019-01-12" I'd get `{"name": "Comment 2", "date": "2019-01-11", "character_count": 2000}` for "Post 1" and `{"name": "Comment 1", "date": "2019-01-10", "character_count": 400}` for "Post 2".

Now I need to aggregate, but how do I do that? For example, I need to get average character count. Or maybe number of "posts" that have character count under a certain value?

There's an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567862/elasticsearch-aggregate-a-script-field), where it is suggested to put the script into the aggregation itself. While that works, it feels like an awful waste to sort and filter the list every time I need to get a single attribute.

Or maybe I don't even need the scripted fields and there's a different solution?