# Average of differences calculated between two date fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-7

I'm working on a project that uses `Elasticsearch` to store data and show some complex statistics.

I have an **index** in that looks like this:

```
Reservation {
  id: number
  check_in: Date
  check_out: Date
  created_at: Date
  // other fields...
}
```

I need to **calculate the average days' difference between** `check_in` **and** `created_at` **of my** `Reservation`s in a specific date range and show the result as a number.

I tried this `query`:

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "avgDates": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "expression",
        "source": "doc['created_at'].value - doc['check_in'].value"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "{{lastMountTimestamp}}",
              "lte": "{{currentTimestamp}}"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "avgBetweenDates": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "avgDates"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Dates fields** are saved in **ISO 8601** form (eg: 2020-03-11T14:25:15+00:00), I don't know if this could produce issues.

It catches some hits, So, the query works for sure! but, it always returns `null` as the value of the `avgBetweenDates` aggregation.

I need a result like this:

```
"aggregations": {
    "avgBetweenDates": {
        "value": 3.14159 // Π is just an example!
    }
}
```

Any ideas will help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripted Fields are not stored fields in ES. You can only perform aggregation on the stored fields as `scripted fields` are created on the fly.

You can simply move the script logic in the [Average Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) as shown below. Note that for the sake of understanding, I've created sample mapping, documents, query and its response.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_date_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "check_in":{
        "type":"date",
        "format": "date_time"
      },
      "check_out":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_time"
      },
      "created_at":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_time"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_date_index/_doc/1
{
  "check_in": "2019-01-15T00:00:00.000Z",
  "check_out": "2019-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
  "created_at": "2019-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
}

POST my_date_index/_doc/2
{
  "check_in": "2019-01-15T00:00:00.000Z",
  "check_out": "2019-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
  "created_at": "2019-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST my_date_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_dates_diff": {
      "avg": {
        "script": """
          ZonedDateTime d1 = doc['created_at'].value;
          ZonedDateTime d2 = doc['check_in'].value;
          long differenceInMillis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(d1, d2);
          return Math.abs(differenceInMillis/86400000);
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice, that you wanted difference in *number of days*. The above logic does that.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_dates_diff" : {
      "value" : 3.5              <---- Average in Number of Days
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution works for me!  Thank you Kamal. But, Am I forced to remap my index just to add the `"format": "date_time"`. If yes, is there is a way to do so without deleting my old one.

Comment: @MalekBoubakri You don't have to. Could you run the `agg` on the existing index you have and let me know if that works for you. I think it should work but if it doesn't please let me know.

Comment: @Kamal I think it works without it! In fact, I think I shouldn't use it on all dates in my case! because it looks like the format `date_time` === `strict_date_time` and it force me to pass time value all the time, maybe `strict_date_optional_time` is better in some cases. Now, I am reading the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats) for further info. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Scripted fields created within the `_search` context can [only be consumed within that scope](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-use-a-script-field-inside-aggregate/191190/2). They're not visible within the `aggregations`! This means you'll have to go with either

- moving your script to the `aggs` section and [doing the `avg` there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567894/8160318)
- a [scripted metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation (quite slow and difficult to get right)
- or creating a `dateDifference` field at index time (preferably an `int` -- a difference of the timestamps) which will enable you to perform powerful numeric aggs like [extended stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-extendedstats-aggregation.html) which provide a statistically useful output like:

```
{
    ...

    "aggregations": {
        "grades_stats": {
           "count": 2,
           "min": 50.0,
           "max": 100.0,
           "avg": 75.0,
           "sum": 150.0,
           "sum_of_squares": 12500.0,
           "variance": 625.0,
           "std_deviation": 25.0,
           "std_deviation_bounds": {
            "upper": 125.0,
            "lower": 25.0
           }
        }
    }
}
```

and are always faster than computing the timestamp differences with a script.

Comment: Thank you jzzfs. I taked this **first option** , I moved my script to the `aggs` section as shown in your link and demonstrated in the accepted answer. Still believe that the **third option** is always the most performant and better choice but in my case, I need to query it.

Comment: You can query it! It's a regular new field. You can query _and_ aggregate on it.